# RxJS Operator to compose observables into state?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am currently facing a pretty common problem, when it comes to asynchronous execution, state handling and the indentation hell.

Let's say there is a REST call that requests adding user information (`user_info`) to a user, notify his contacts of that change and return the inserted or modified user information in the response. But a user `object` does only know all the ids of his `user_info` objects via 1 to n relation.

Call Sequence:

```
request -> saveUserInfo -> updateUser -> notifyContacts -> response
```

`saveToDb`, `updateUser` and `notifyContacts` are all functions that perform an asynchronous side effect and can not simply be composed as they all have different inputs and outputs and depend on the order of execution.

Here is a loose representation of the function headers

```
function saveUserInfo(payload): Promise<UserInfo[]> { /*...*/ }
function updateUser(user_id, user_infos): Promise<User> { /*...*/ }
function sendNotification(user, user_infos): Promise<void> { /*...*/ }
```

To write this request handler, I was currently working a lot with `mergeMap` to subscribe to the inner observables that performed the current asynchronous action. It looked something like this:

```
function handleRequest(payload, user_id) {
  return saveUserInfo(payload).pipe(
    mergeMap(user_infos =>
      from(updateUser(user_id, user_infos)).pipe(
        mergeMap(user =>
          from(notifyContacts(user, user_infos)).pipe(map(() => user_infos))
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
```

I was not satisfied with this solution, because there will be more logic added to this in the future and I know this can become cumbersome at some point.

So I searched through the RxJS documentation and sadly did not find a clever way to pipe these asynchronous calls together in a much more pleasing way. The biggest issue is, that I am not really able to completely formulate the problem here in a few words, which might have lead me to write this question.

Does anyone know a better solution to this? I am sure there must be something!

Preferably without helper funtions and in pure RxJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a high order mapping operator(e.g `mergeMap` and its friends) and if the provided callback returns a **promise**, you don't have to do `() => from(promise)`. `mergeMap` will automatically do it for you.

With this in mind, I'd change this:

```
function handleRequest(payload, user_id) {
  return saveUserInfo(payload).pipe(
    mergeMap(user_infos =>
      from(updateUser(user_id, user_infos)).pipe(
        mergeMap(user =>
          from(notifyContacts(user, user_infos)).pipe(map(() => user_infos))
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
```

into this

```js
function handleRequest(payload, user_id) {
  return from(saveUserInfo(payload)) // `saveUserInfo(payload)` returns a promise
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(user_infos => forkJoin(of({ user_infos }), updateUser(user_id, user_infos)),
      mergeMap(([acc, user]) => forkJoin(of({ ...acc, otherPropsHere: true }), notifyContacts(user, user_infos))),
      map(([acc]) => acc['user_infos'])
    ),
  )
}
```

`forkJoin` will emit an **array** after all its provided [`ObservableInput`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/types.ts#L76)s emitted at least one value and completed.

As you can see, the first element of the returned array is the accumulator.

Comment: Thank you for the `forkJoin` idea, it's interesting. it seems like you even get type inference, because of RxJS way of overloading, instead of using array types, that's pretty cool

Comment: It looks like you can use `pluck(0, "user_infos")` instead of `map(([acc]) => acc['user_infos'])`

Answer (score 1):

As I could not find anything helpful on the internet, I came up with a higher order function to provide me with a pipeable operator, that could potentially solve my problem, I called it `sourceMap`.

It should subscribe to an inner observable via `mergeMap` and merge the result of it into a keyed state object.

```
const sourceMap = <S, T extends Record<string, any>>(
  predicate: (acc: T) => Promise<S> | Observable<S>,
  key?: keyof T
) => {
  return mergeMap((acc: T) =>
    from(predicate(acc)).pipe(map(res => (key ? { ...acc, [key]: res } : acc)))
  )
}
```

Implementation looks like this:

```
function handleRequest(payload, user_id): Observable<UserInfo[]> {
  const state$ = of({ user_infos: [] as UserInfo[], user: {} as User })

 return state$.pipe(
    sourceMap(() => saveUserInfo(user_id, payload), 'user_info'),
    sourceMap(({ user_info }) => updateUser(user_id, user_info), 'user'),
    sourceMap(({ user_info, user }) => notifyContacts(user, user_info)),
    pluck('user_info')
  )
}
```

Still looking for a better solution to this!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```js
function saveUserInfo(payload: Payload): Promise<UserInfo[]>;
function updateUser(user_id: string, user_infos: UserInfo[]): Promise<User>;
function sendNotification(user: User, user_infos: UserInfo[]): Promise<void>;

function handleRequest(payload: Payload, user_id: string): Observable<UserInfo[]> {
  return from(saveUserInfo(payload)).pipe(
    switchMap(user_infos => updateUser(user_id, user_infos).then(user => ({ user, user_infos }))),
    switchMap(({ user, user_infos }) => sendNotification(user, user_infos).then(() => user_infos))
  );
}
```

Comment: Using promise chaining would break error handling I guess.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Once you call `then` you must provide a `catch`, otherwise `then` returns a new Promise and `catch` will never be called on the new Promise. That will result in error swallowing. Now if an error occurs in the underlying Promise, `then` will be called anyways and the payload is just `undefined`, hard to debug.

Comment: If you don't provide an `onRejected` handler then the Promise will by default throw the error it received, not swallow it. RxJs handles this correctly and passes errors on to the `error` handler in the observer. See this stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hqbzd4?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: In this case `updateUser(user_id, user_infos).then(user => ({ user, user_infos }))` is essentially the same as `from(updateUser(user_id, user_infos)).pipe(map(user => ({ user, user_infos })))`

Comment: Thanks for lighting that up! I did not know about this RxJS magic happening.